# What is wrong with "to temple is full of potholes" in this sentence?

Tags: exam-questions, error

> In the following question, some part of the sentence may have errors. Find out which part of the sentence has an error and select the appropriate
>   option. If a sentence is free from error, select 'No Error'.
>
> > The road from(A)/my house(B)/to temple is full of potholes.(C)/No error(D)

the above question was asked in my exam and the answer given is (C).
but I didn't get it.

Comment: I think it was meant to be "to *the* temple", but it is a bad example, because "temple" can be used without any article when referring to an institution.

Comment: @user3169 The usage you bring up is valid, but in this case, it is grammatically impossible to omit "the." I go to temple every Saturday can mean you go to _some_ temple, whether it's the one that's closest or the one that you feel like going to at the time, but a "road" is a physical thing that can only go to one specific temple.

Comment: @joiedevivre   But you wouldn't say "I am going to *the* church on Sunday", but rather "I am going to church on Sunday", right? Referring to the event, not the physical location.

Comment: @user3169 True. My point was merely that in the OP's sentence, the definite article is required. Leaving it out _is_ strictly speaking an error in this sentence, so I think it's an okay exam question.

Answer (score 2):

The way you wrote the question makes it hard to understand what each letter is referencing.

Regardless, the error is in the "to temple" part. It should say "to **the** temple"

Comment: sorry, but that was the format in which question was asked to me in exam.

Comment: The letters mark the end of the section where there might be an error, with the final choice being “no error”. It’s fairly standard for these sorts of exam questions.